# Remove VIEW permission automatically from Guest Role when a site-page is added

Tags: configuration, liferay, liferay-6, administration

In Liferay when a page is added to the Site it by default gives `VIEW` permission to the Guest role.

[image: Permission window for a Site Page]

Is there any way (either through configuration or through hook or other) to disable this so that by default `VIEW` permission is disabled for Guest role when a new page is added to the Site?

Comment: Well, while page[Layout-in Liferay low level context] is added as Public page , Liferay assigns default guess permissions defined in sites.xml for Layout model. Basically there are two ways to avoid it through ext development.1.remove guest default permissions from sites.xml 2.change code in LayoutLocalServiceImpl in ext by over-riding addLayout method by having addGroupPermissions boolean value as false .

Answer (score 5):

Well, while page [Layout-in Liferay low level context] is added as Public page, Liferay assigns default permissions to `GUEST` role defined in `sites.xml` for Layout model.

Basically there are two ways to avoid it through ext development:

1. remove guest default permissions from `sites.xml`
2. change code in `LayoutLocalServiceImpl` in ext by over-riding `addLayout` method by having `addGroupPermissions` boolean value as `false`.

Comment: Now the requirement is how to remove Guest role dynamically from pages to whom Guest role view permission is already assigned.
I mean is there any way to remove previously assigned view permission of Guest role from all ready created pages instead of manually removing view permission of Guest role from manage permission tab.

Comment: Hmm. for that you can write some utility-portlet which takes all public pages and using `ResourcePermissionServiceUtil.removeResourcePermission` , you can remove view permission for Guest role.

Answer (score 5):

There are ways (through liferay Configuration and Ext) with which you can restrict VIEW of Site public pages for those Users who don't explicitly have that permission.

***1st Approach***

So this can be achieved by setting this property to `false` in portal-ext.properties:

```
permissions.check.guest.enabled=false
```

But by setting this property what will happen is that Guest role would make sense only for Users who have not logged-in, once the User logs-in even if there is a VIEW permission on Guest for a page or asset the User won't be able to view it unless the User has that permission.

So Guest role would be rendered completely useless even if you give all the permissions to Guest role.

For users who have not logged-in, you can send them to login page with some logic.

***2nd approach***

1) Updating site.xml in EXT-plugin to disable default `VIEW` permissions for guest while adding Site pages.

By doing so when site page is added, by default Guest role's view permission is unchecked.